# How do I keep my page from jumping around after every postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using an UpdatePanel and the form auto-saves after every `onTextChanged` trigger. However, the page keeps going to the top. How do i keep the page where the onfocus is?

I'm currently using the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` but that's not working:

```
<%@ Page Title="Welcome" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="account-master.master" 
        AutoEventWireup="true" 
        CodeFile="Welcome.aspx.cs" 
        Inherits="Welcome"  
        MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" 
    %>
```

I used the following javascript code to fix this issue:

```
'window.onscroll = function () {
        var scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
        if (scrollY == 0) {
            if (window.pageYOffset) {
                scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
            }
            else {
                scrollY = (document.body.parentElement) ? document.body.parentElement.scrollTop : 0;
            }
        }
        if (scrollY > 0) {
            var input = document.getElementById("scrollY");
            if (input == null) {
                input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                input.setAttribute("id", "scrollY");
                input.setAttribute("name", "scrollY");
                document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
            }
            input.value = scrollY;
        }
    };'
```

Comment: make sure the server-side code returns only to a javascript callback.  It sounds like it's loading a new page each time.

Comment: Looking into this further it sounds like you'll want to use "onchange" event instead and link that to a javascript that fires the get or post and then have your controller return to the js callback (or not return anything at all...)

Comment: @pcalkins, thanks! i think i got it using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work. runs on windowload

```
window.onload = function () {
        var scrollY = parseInt('<%=Request.Form["scrollY"] %>');             
        if (!isNaN(scrollY)) {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
        }
    };
    window.onscroll = function () {
        var scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
        if (scrollY == 0) {
            if (window.pageYOffset) {
                scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
            }
            else {
                scrollY = (document.body.parentElement) ? document.body.parentElement.scrollTop : 0;
            }
        }
        if (scrollY > 0) {
            var input = document.getElementById("scrollY");
            if (input == null) {
                input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                input.setAttribute("id", "scrollY");
                input.setAttribute("name", "scrollY");
                document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
            }
            input.value = scrollY;
        }
    };
```